# How to handle onchange event on input type=file in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, input

The code is:

```
<input ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" type="file"
```

The following works fine:

```
<input onchange="javascript:alert('hola');" ID="fileUpload1"  runat="server" type="file"
```

I'd like to get this result using jQuery, but that doesn't work:

```
$('#fileUpload1').change(function (e) {
    alert("hola");
});
```

I am missing something? (Edit: Yes I missed include the *.js file.)

Comment: The id of the element is `"fileUpload1"` not `"fileupload1"`. Are you also running your code after the element exists  and you have included jQuery etc? Also check your browser console for javascript errors.

Comment: I searched for similar keywords but I'm looking for "no jQuery" version...

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/NbGBj/

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("#upload").change(function() {
        alert('changed!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Or could be:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    alert("hola");
});
```

To be specific: `$('input[type=file]#fileUpload1').change(...`

Answer (score 5):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH4QD/1) works fine for me.

```
$(document).delegate(':file', 'change', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

Note: .delegate() is the fastest event-binding method for jQuery < 1.7: [event-binding methods](http://jsperf.com/on-vs-bind-vs-delegate-vs-native/2)

Answer (score 4):

It should work fine, are you wrapping the code in a `$(document).ready()` call? If not use that or use `live` i.e.

```
$('#fileupload1').live('change', function(){ 
    alert("hola");
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngd7t/3/) of this working against jQuery 1.4.4

Comment: live is deprecated, one should use on() nowadays

Comment: He is using v1.4.4 which doesnt support `on()`

Comment: `live` is deprecated for all jQuery versions, use `.delegate`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

**HTML:**

```
<input ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" type="file">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#fileUpload1").on('change',function() {
    alert('Works!!');
});
```

​

Comment: Sorry for I didn't see the problem properly...now check @Esailija

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#fileupload').bind('change', function (e) { //dynamic property binding
alert('hello');// message you want to display
});
```

You can use this one also