# how to postback to my action after triggering hidden file upload control in mvc

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I need to invoke file upload control on a button click. The file upload control is not visible to user.

On click event of button, I triggered the file upload's click event. So now file upload displays and I can select a file. The problem is after I select a file and click on Open, I want to postback to my action. Can someone guide me how it is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### The idea:

Select the form: `$('form#the_form_id');` then submit it: `$('form#the_form_id').submit();`.

### Event handling:

In order to execute the above code only after the user has selected the desired files all you need to do is bind it (the code) as the callback to an event that happens after the user selected a file.

```
$('input[type=file]#the_fileinput_id').bind('change', function() {
    $('form#the_form_id').submit();
});
```

### Demo:

Demo in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NbGBj/ provided by this post other SO answer: [How to handle onchange event on input type=file in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860721/how-to-handle-onchange-event-on-input-type-file-in-jquery)

### X-Browser compatibility:

AFAIK onChange event does not exist in IE (for any input type - not limited to file inputs). jQuery developers had to create a workaround for it and it was added as of jQuery 1.5.1. So your jQuery version must be at least that.

Comment: hey tried binding change event to file upload control. on button click, instead of invoking file upload control, it posted back to action result.

Comment: Code, $("myfileUpload").bind('change', function() {$('form').submit(); }); Please tell me where I am goin wrong

Comment: Oops had a typo at my end.. file upload control is displayed and as I select a file and click Open, i get an exception, "Access denied". In jquery it crashes in code block with comment "Prevent retriggering same event since we have already bubbled it above". I am using IE8

Comment: As a web developer please try using **literally** any other browser this sweet world has to offer. After we establish if the code works in a normal browser we can try and manage the ritual incantations needed to overcome IE syndrome.

Comment: Mihai, The code works in Firefox.. I am able to reach the action result.. It doesn't work in IE thou..

Comment: OK, what is you jQuery version? AFAIK `onChange` event does not exist in IE. jQuery developers had to create a workaround for it and it was added as of jQuery 1.5.1 I think.

Answer (score 0):

when the file input is changed, you want the form to be submitted, so:

for this html:

```
<form action="...">
   <input class="file" type="file" />
</form>
```

the javasctript that will do the job:

```
$('input.file').change(function(){
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: It throws an exception, "Access denied". In jquery it crashes in code block with comment "Prevent retriggering same event since we have already bubbled it above". I am using IE8.