# How to instantly upload only images in a form which also contains other fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a form which is spread across multiple pages. The form has multiple fields,(text, image , email , etc ..) I want to upload the only the images as soon the user choose the image, but the form should not be submitted unless the user completes all the fields.
I'am Using CarrierWave::RMagick

Comment: Use uplodify with paperclip

Comment: I'am using CarrierWave::RMagick

Comment: Then use uplodify with carrierWave gem....you can see github example here for same https://github.com/n0ne/Uploadify-Carrierwave-Rails-3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using JavaScript. Make use of `onchange` event to post the data, for example refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860721/how-to-handle-onchange-event-on-input-type-file-in-jquery). If you don't want to reinvent the wheel on JavaScript front, you can use exisiting JavaScript library like [BlueImp JQuery File upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to submit photo to server.

On Ruby side you can have an endpoint(controller method POST) which would accept image and probably an identifier to signify what scenario the image has been submitted for.