# Uploading same file into text box after clearing it, is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, google-chrome

I am trying to work with this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/200eoamf/1/

that is the code in part, you can see all the code in jsfiddle:

```
var onFileReadFn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function() {

    var fileContents = reader.result;

    // invoke parsed function on scope
    scope.$apply(function() {
        onFileReadFn(scope, {
            'contents' : fileContents
        });
    });
};

reader.readAsText(element[0].files[0]);
```

The following issue occurs in *Chrome* browser, but not in *Firefox*:

If I choose file, say **myfile.txt**, it will appear in the text box.
However, if I manually clear that window by selecting the entire text and deleting it, and then trying to upload the same file **myfile.txt** again, it won't upload. Why is this happening and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: "manually clearing it" do you mean by content of the textarea element or how?

Comment: Yes, just select entire uploaded text in the textarea by mouse or Ctrl-A, and then hit 'Backspace', then try to Choose the same file. It won't upload.

Comment: It is working for me under Firefox v41

Comment: Yes, it looks like this problem shows in Chrome and not in Firefox. I will change the title and add this fact to description. If you happen to know why this occurs in Chrome only, please, let me know.

Comment: BTW, I just noted the angular version in that jsfiddle is 1.2 which is nowadays obsolete. Do you need this working under a specific version or only the latest stable?

Comment: To be clear: your code is working. The problem relay on the file input ´onchange´ event which, under chrome, fires if the new selected file is different from the previous one (if any). You can simply verify this [by your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11860770/1505348).

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks for clarification. However, I still do not get how I redefine/overrride 'onchage' event so that it would fire off regardless of previously loaded file. Would it be easy to make this change in jsfiddle so that I could understand? (Any AngularJS version, especially latest would do, no need in 1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, one is use a *Clear* button so the user can manually do it, another option is to clear the value of the previous file when the user clicks on the input. Here is the later: http://jsfiddle.net/200eoamf/12/

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  element.val(null);
});
```

Thanks to [Blake Plumb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161353/blake-plumb) for [the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670769/jquery-detecting-if-a-file-has-been-selected-in-the-file-input#comment38046117_5670938)! :)